# How do I output a string with curly-braces and quotes exactly?

Tags: freemarker

I can't figure out the correct escaping / no parse commands for this use case.

## Case 1

Template Input:

```
foo.bar: {"key_a":"val_a", "key_b":"val_b"}
```

Output:

```
foo.bar:
    key_a: val_a
    key_b: val_b
```

## Case 2

Template Input:

```
foo.bar: '{"key_a":"val_a", "key_b":"val_b"}'   // Added single quotes
```

Output:

```
foo.bar: '{"key_a":"val_a", "key_b":"val_b"}'
```

## Desired Output

```
foo.bar: {"key_a":"val_a", "key_b":"val_b"}     // No quotes
```

Comment: What do you mean by "template input", what parses that? How does the template look (I see no `${...}` or such anywhere)?

Answer (score 0):

Just assign value to a variable and use double quotes:

```
<#assign foo = "{\"key_a\":\"val_a\", \"key_b\":\"val_b\"}"/>
foo.bar: ${foo}
```

You can check online in https://try.freemarker.apache.org/

Comment: For the string literal it's more convenient to use `'` in this case, and then no escaping is needed. Also, why would assigning to a variable help?